# Grails Binding between multiselect, enum , command object and domain class

Tags: grails, enums, command

I am working on a project which uses a multiselect field.

My domain class is defined as:

```
class RoomWanted{

  Set<MateAgeRange> mateAgeRanges

}
```

Then:

```
public enum MateAgeRange {
   TWENTIES('18-29')
   ,THIRTIES('30-39')
   ,FOURTIES("40-49")
   ,FIFTIES("50-59")
   ,SIXTIES("60+")



    final String value

    private MateAgeRange(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    String toString() { value }
    String getKey() { name() }


    static belongsTo=[roomWanted:RoomWanted]
}
```

My command object is:

```
class RoomWantedDetailsCommand implements Serializable {

      Set<MateAgeRange> mateAgeRanges
}
```

I want to have the create page, edit page, show page

Here is my create page

```
<g:select name="mateAgeRanges" multiple="true" from="${MateAgeRange?.values()}"  optionKey="key" />
```

My command object 'cmd' gets the value

```
print cmd.mateAgeRanges
```

gives the value 
 [30-39, 50-59] when I select these two.

But it does not bind to the field in the domain class.
In the show page,
if I use 
    cmd.mateAgeRanges
it returns [].

Comment: why do you have a command object for something which is already represented by a domain class?

Comment: It is used in the controller for easing the process of create, edit and to validate data at the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain class should be defined as:

```
class RoomWantedDetailsCommand implements Serializable {

      Set<MateAgeRange> mateAgeRanges

      static hasMany = [ mateAgeRanges:MateAgeRange ]
}
```

Enum is defined as:

```
public enum MateAgeRange {
   TWENTIES('18-29')
   ,THIRTIES('30-39')
   ,FOURTIES("40-49")
   ,FIFTIES("50-59")
   ,SIXTIES("60+")



final String value

private MateAgeRange(String value) {
    this.value = value
}

String toString() { value }
String getKey() { name() }


static belongsTo=[roomWanted:RoomWanted]
}
```

In the edit page:

```
  <g:select name="mateAgeRanges" multiple="true" from="${MateAgeRange?.values()}" optionKey="key" value="${roomWanted?.mateAgeRanges}"/>
```

In the show page:
      ${roomWanted?.mateAgeRanges }

In the create page

Answer (score 0):

add hasMany to your `RoomWanted` class

```
class RoomWanted{

  Set<MateAgeRange> mateAgeRanges

  static hasMany = [ mateAgeRanges:MateAgeRange ]

}
```

if you don't, GORM doesn't fill this association in full-auto.

Then you should use `roomWanted.addToMateAgeRanges(..)` to fill-in the values

Comment: Thankyou. It works correctly in the create and show pages. The values are stores in the db. But in the edit page, when I use   <g:select name="mateAgeRanges" multiple="true" from="${MateAgeRange?.values()}"  optionKey="key" />  it does not show the values from db selected. Values are actually coming from the db.

Comment: you need to add @value: `<g:select name="mateAgeRanges" multiple="true" from="${MateAgeRange?.values()}" optionKey="key" value="${roomWanted?.mateAgeRanges}"/>`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. I was struggling with this for 2 days. Here I think the values stored in db are 18-29, 20-29 etc.. For searching purposes, I need TWENTIES, THIRTEES, FOURTEES etc.. Is there any change needed in the current code.

Comment: you can use `valueOf()' method somehow. I've never used it, so you have to try it out :)

Comment: this is the 3rd question already. you should've been banned for offtopic by now